# Robust Linear Optimization for avoiding diminishing returns

Tags: linear-programming, robust-optimization

My engineering problem can be formulated as an LP as shown below

\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x}}~~&\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x} \\
\mbox{s.t.}~~~&\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x} \leq B~~,~~\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}\leq 1~~,~~\mathbf{x}\geq 0
\end{align}
Let $\mathbf{a}\geq 0$ and $\mathbf{b} \geq 0$. Physically, $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}$ corresponds to the profit we make and $\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}$ is the cost we incur and $B$ is the budget available to us. Second constraint corresponds to the fact that elements $x_i$ of $\mathbf{x}$ should sum to 1. Third constraint corresponds to element-wise positivity. Due to unavoidable process errors, values of $\mathbf{a}$ is often erroneous due to inherent noise in our system. Thus, the profit predicted by the above problem may not realize (but spend will). For example, let's say we solve above optimization problem with the given $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ and then deploy the $\mathbf{x}$ in production. Then, its a common occurrence wherein we realized only 90% of the objective (profit) expected offline for the same cost. In fact, consider that we had solved the problem show below to get $\mathbf{x}_2^*$
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x}}~~&\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x} \\
\mbox{s.t.}~~~&\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x} \leq B~~,~~\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}\leq 
1~~,~~\mathbf{x}\geq 0 \\
&\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x} \leq 0.9*\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}_1^*
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{x}_1^*$ is the solution from the original problem. Then, we have seen often that $\mathbf{x}_2^*$ can be a much better solution in terms of the cost incurred. In particular, we want to avoid scenarios where the gain in profit is very marginal (say 10%) compared to the increase in cost (say 100%). What are the standard approaches in such scenarios?. Say I can assume that the errors in $\mathbf{a}_i$ are uniformly distributed within a 10% interval.